# Android continuous recording in the background with edit frames

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, recording, android-camerax

I would like to implement camera app and I do not know which API to use it. What APIs would you choose for these criteria?

- Activity shows full screen camera preview.
- User can start / stop video recording with / without sound from Activity.
- If activity is in the foreground, show full screen camera preview (probably start in onResume()).
- If activity goes to the background, preview will stop (probably in onPause()), but recording will continue in the background with Notification displayed.
- Add date + time + some drawables to all video frames which go to the codec (not to the preview) for foreground / background recording.
- Android API 23+ (can be higher).

API to choose from:
Camera 1, Camera 2, CameraX, MediaRecorder, MediaCodec + Muxer, OpenGL surface, ..?

What API would you implement it with? Are there any examples? Kotlin preferred.
Activity / Fragment / Service is not part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to edit each frame before sending it to the video encoder, you can use either camera2 or cameraX (ImageAnalysis+Preview use cases), up to 1080p resolution at least.  If you want to record higher than 1080p then you probably need to use camera2.

For the editing, you could use EGL rendering, which would be fairly efficient, but text rendering is complicated so you'd want to find some libraries to help with that. Though that's also true of editing on the CPU.

With Camera2, for EGL you can create a SurfaceTexture for input that you can pass to Camera2 (via a Surface) and also write out to a Surface that goes to a MediaRecorder/MediaCodec. For CPU, you might want a Camera->ImageReader / ImageWriter->MediaRecorder pair with editing in the middle.

For CameraX ImageAnalysis, you get Image objects you'd need to read from for CPU or send to an ImageWriter for EGL processing.

If you're saving videos to disk, MediaRecorder should work fine. MediaCodec + MediaMuxer gets you more control (send frames over network, etc) but is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

On camera side, Camera2 is the only choice as Video is not supported in CameraX at the moment.